# Why isn't my filepath to an image working?

Tags: php, html

I have content which is more or less repeated in more than one webpage so I have created a template and stored this in a shared folder. I have a number of files in this shared folder such as a header and footer and they are all working fine.

I created my shared folder (called includes) in the initialise.php file which I call at the start of my files.

```
define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));  // "PRIVATE PATH" LOCATION IS THIS LOCATION (__FILE__)
define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH)); // "PROJECT PATH" LOCATION IS ONE UP FROM THE PRIVATE PATH - THIS IS THE PROJECT ROOT
define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . '/public'); //"PUBLIC_PATH" IS THE PROJECT PATH /'public' FOLDER
define("SHARED_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . '/includes'); // "SHARED_PATH" IS PRIVATE PATH/'templates' FOLDER
```

In my new template I again try to go to this shared path folder to access these images using the following line of code:

```
{print (include(SHARED_PATH .'"<img src = img/icons/mix_vertical.jpg>"'));}
```

However, I get an error now:

> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\wamp64\www\sites\PROJECTS\OrangoJapan.com/includes"<img
>   src = img/icons/mix_vertical.jpg>"' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wam....

Comment: if your issue is PATHS, its simpler for us if you show us the file tree of your website. Also you should use absolute path instead of relative path that way ur 100%sure they work no matter where the file is

Comment: Actually, I guess the question should be how to put an image in a shared folder and call the image. I don't think it's a paths issue as the paths appear to work for my other files on the shared folder. I guess I should have asked, how to use the print or echo statement with an include statement with a specified Shared Path...?

{print (include(SHARED_PATH .'/img/icons/mix_vertical.jpg'););}

Comment: The comment is right, it is better to use absolute paths!
The path used for image in "src" are like URI,  so they do not depend on the path on your system (they can, but not necessary).
If my memories are correct: Let imagine you browse the URL "http://foobaz.com/testing", and using `<img src="img/nurf.png">`. The image access will be at: http://foobaz.com/testing/img/nurf.png.
Here we are talking about URI, not about path on your FS.

Comment: You better explain what a shared folder is, what your workflow is and what actually happening. I (and others too) have no idea if your path is correct or if you have access to the file. Also, show final HTML

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback so far. So I created a shared folder which I put in templates and stuff which I use multiple times. I defined this with an intialize.php using the following code:

Comment: Hi lucifer63 Ngob BenoitF. I have just added the absolute path and it seems to work fine. I will process just using the absolute paths. Many thanks all for your help.